# Reduce padding around text below zero

Tags: html, css

Take the following example:

https://jsfiddle.net/uq57mn0a/

... having a simple element as follows:

```
<span style="font-size:40px; font-weight:bolder; padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px; padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; border: 1px solid black; border-radius: 5px; background-color:#aaf">AB 123</span>
```

I want to reduce the amount of padding at the top and bottom of the text, i.e. to have less of the coloured background.

But I'm already at the minimum padding (zero) and going negative does nothing.  What can I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can adjust `line-height` and make the element `inline-block`

```css
span {
  font-weight: bolder;
  padding:0 10px;
  display:inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #aaf;
  line-height: 0.7em /* 0.7 * font-size */
}
```

```html
<span style="font-size:40px">AB 123</span>
<span style="font-size:30px">AB 123</span>
<span style="font-size:20px">AB 123</span>
```

With another font:

```css
span {
  font-family:arial;
  font-weight: bolder;
  padding:0 10px;
  display:inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #aaf;
  line-height: 0.7em; /* 0.7 * font-size */
}
```

```html
<span style="font-size:40px">AB 123</span>
<span style="font-size:30px">AB 123</span>
<span style="font-size:20px">AB 123</span>
```

Comment: Note though that this is *highly font specific*

Comment: I don't think it's a good practice to reduce the line-height than the font's size.

Comment: Either we can use *line-height:0.75;* rather than using pixels

Comment: @Viira if you have another solution for this then go for it :) .. the OP want this, so I don't see another way

Comment: 0.7em is not solution, as per @Paulie_D it is font specific but I guess author got what he is seeking for.

Comment: Nope, the answer is yours! I'm just saying my opinion :)

Comment: @DhavalPanchal euh .. you answered the same I think, no? And I know it's font specific

Comment: @TemaniAfif Yes we both are right and both fulfil requirement of author. +1 for both of us :)

Answer (score 1):

> Because span is by default inline element so we convert it into
>   display: inline-block; and reduce line-height.

Try this.

**HTML:**

```
<span>AB 123</span>
```

**CSS**

```
span {
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: bolder;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #aaf;
    line-height: 28px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```